# Power Query: Refer to a Column by Name Stored as a Text Parameter

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I am using Power Query in Excel for Microsoft 365.

Here is my source data table (whose table name is **Source**):

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Name | Alt.Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 21 | 31 | 41 | Dog | Fido |
| 12 | 22 | 32 | 42 | Cat | Fluffy |
|  | 23 | 33 | 43 | Ostrich | Jan |
| 14 | 24 |  | 44 | Parakeet | Bob |
| 15 | 25 | 35 | 45 | Trout | Cindy |

I have defined two text parameters:

- `ColToKeep` specifies which **one** of the columns `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`, and `Col4` to keep. The columns not specified will be discarded.
- `NameToKeep` specifies which of the columns `Name` and `Alt.Name` to keep. The column not specified will be discarded.

My goal is to develop a Power Query to:

1. Remove all columns except the two specified by `ColToKeep` and `NameToKeep`
2. Filter out rows where there is a **null** in the column specified by `ColToKeep`

Assuming I set `ColToKeep` to **Col3** and assuming I set `NameToKeep` to **Alt.Name**, the desired result is:

| Col3 | Alt.Name |
| --- | --- |
| 31 | Fido |
| 32 | Fluffy |
| 33 | Jan |
| 35 | Cindy |

However, the actual (**incorrect**) result is:

| Col3 | Alt.Name |
| --- | --- |
| 31 | Fido |
| 32 | Fluffy |
| 33 | Jan |
|  | Bob |
| 35 | Cindy |

Here is the M Language code for my Power Query:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Source"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Col1", Int64.Type}, {"Col2", Int64.Type}, {"Col3", Int64.Type}, {"Col4", Int64.Type}, {"Name", Text.Type}, {"Alt.Name", Text.Type}}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",{ColToKeep, NameToKeep}),
    // #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each [ColToKeep] <> null and [ColToKeep] <> "")
    // #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each ColToKeep <> null and ColToKeep <> "")
    // #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Other Columns"){0} <> null and Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Other Columns"){0} <> "")
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

It is the **#"Filtered Rows"** applied step that is going wrong. In the code above, I show three (commented-out) attempts I've made at implementing this applied step.

In the first attempt, I simply refer to the column names directly (with brackets). However, `ColToKeep` and `NameToKeep` are taken to be references to the columns of interest, not as text strings that hold the column names. An error is thrown because, e.g., there is no column named **ColToKeep**.

In the second attempt, I again refer to the column names directly, but this time without brackets. This does not throw an error, but I get the incorrect output shown above.

In the third attempt, I refer to the columns by their position since I don't know until runtime which columns are being kept. After the preceding **#"Removed Other Columns"** applied step is executed, there will be two columns remaining. I assumed their position indexes would be 0 and 1, but I'm suspecting the position indexes have not yet been adjusted when the `Table.SelectRows` call executes and that I am therefore not referencing the column I intend to when filtering out **null** values. This does not throw an error, but it does generate the incorrect output shown above.

How may I filter out rows based on **null** values in the column named by the parameter `ColToKeep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporarily drop the headers to the first row which will number the columns as 1 and 2, then filter out the nulls, then re-promote the first row as headers:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Source"]}[Content],
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{ColToKeep, NameToKeep}),
    #"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(#"Removed Other Columns"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Demoted Headers",{{"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Column1] <> null)),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each [Column2] <> null),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Filtered Rows1", [PromoteAllScalars=true])
in
    #"Promoted Headers"
```