# Power Query: Refer to a Column by Name Stored as a Text Parameter (REDUX)

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I am using Power Query in Excel for Microsoft 365.

The question I am about to pose is very similar to one I recently posed and for which an elegant answer was given. That question is here:
[Power Query: Refer to a Column by Name Stored as a Text Parameter](https://superuser.com/questions/1808426/power-query-refer-to-a-column-by-name-stored-as-a-text-parameter)

In the question linked above, I needed to filter rows based on the nullness of a column whose position was constant (always the first column) but whose name was difficult to use because it was stored in a text parameter. The answer was to demote the headers (thereby giving them predictable names), filter based on the nullness of **Column1**, and promote the headers (to bring back their original names). The text parameter holding the column's name ended up not coming into play.

In the current question, I again need to filter rows based on the nullness of a column whose name is stored in a text parameter, but this time, it won't always be the first column. It could be the first, second, third, or fourth column. So this time, I really do have to use the parameter that specifies the column name.

I will present my original question again, altered to reflect this new requirement.

Here is my source data table (whose table name is **Source**):

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 21 | 31 | 41 | Dog |
| 12 | 22 | 32 | 42 | Cat |
|  | 23 | 33 | 43 | Ostrich |
| 14 | 24 |  | 44 | Parakeet |
| 15 | 25 | 35 | 45 | Trout |

I have defined one text parameter:

- `FilterColumn` specifies the name of the column that will be used for filtering **null** values. It can take any of the values **Col1**, **Col2**, **Col3**, or **Col4**.

My goal is to develop a Power Query to filter out rows where there is a **null** in the column specified by `FilterColumn`.

Assuming I set `FilterColumn` to **Col3**, the desired result is:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 21 | 31 | 41 | Dog |
| 12 | 22 | 32 | 42 | Cat |
|  | 23 | 33 | 43 | Ostrich |
| 15 | 25 | 35 | 45 | Trout |

Here is the M Language code for my Power Query:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Source"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Col1", Int64.Type}, {"Col2", Int64.Type}, {"Col3", Int64.Type}, {"Col4", Int64.Type}, {"Name", Text.Type}}),
    // #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [FilterColumn] <> null and [FilterColumn] <> "")
    // #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each FilterColumn <> null and FilterColumn <> "")
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

It is the **#"Filtered Rows"** applied step that is going wrong. In the code above, I show two (commented-out) attempts I've made at implementing this applied step.

In the first attempt, I simply refer to the column name directly (with brackets). However, `FilterColumn` is taken to be the name of the column of interest, not as a text parameter holds the column name. An error is thrown because there is no column named **FilterColumn**: `Expression.Error: The field 'FilterColumn' of the record wasn't found.`

In the second attempt, I again refer to the column name directly, but this time without brackets. This does not throw an error, but no rows get filtered out. The output is unchanged from the input.

How may I filter out rows based on **null** values in a column named by the parameter `FilterColumn`?

Comment: two comments 1) believe in your original post you had hardcoded the array you wanted filtered, but did not create a variable to hold that array. You would need variable to work with your commented out rows 2) I can't be certain, but your `each` might only be applying to only the condition before the `and`. I think you will need some type of looping of the `Filtered Column` array. I'm sure a search will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the parameter as a text string, so try:

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", (r)=>Record.Field(r,FilterColumn)<>null)
```

or

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", 
        each Record.Field(_,FilterColumn) <> null 
        and Record.Field(_,FilterColumn) <> "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this also,,,

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectColumns(Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [FilterColumn] <> null and [FilterColumn] <> ""), {"Column1", "Column2", ...})
```

**N.B.**

In this approach.

1. `Table.SelectRows(...)` used to filter rows based on the specified
   condition,  & `Table.SelectColumns(...)` used to select the desired
   columns from the filtered rows.
2. Replace Column1, Column2,  with the actual column names.

*This approach combines filtering Row & Column selection in a single step, which can be more efficient and it may make the code more concise.*